# How to load the yandex to iiframe without redirect

Tags: iframe, redirect, frame

```
<iframe style="border:0;width:100%;" src="http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=text&lr=213"></iframe>
```

THis code are redirecting me to yandex.ru .. Why?? How to load this yandex page to iframe without redirect?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't.

yandex contains some Javascript code to prevent users from loading their page in an iframe:

```
if( document.domain != "yandex.ru" ) { document.domain = "yandex.ru"; }
```